# How do I debug my web.py project in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, web.py

I have my web.py project open in Eclipse, but how can I:

1) Start my project from within Eclipse (and not the console)?
2) Debug my project from within Eclipse (breakpoints, etc..)?

There's no readily-accessible information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very easily, and applies to most projects.

1) Go to your "Debug Configurations" window (under "Debug As").
2) Under "Python Run", add a new configuration.
3) Enter the name of the project.
4) Under "Main Module", click on "Browse" and select the script that you've been starting from the command-line.
5) Save.

Dustin